# Check checkbox selection from within Listener

Tags: java, button, swt, jface

Working away at the moment but have come up with a small problem in JFace.
I need to have a check box that allows the next button to become active.

Here is the code:

```
    Button btnConfirm = new Button(container, SWT.CHECK);

    btnConfirm.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    @Override

    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

          //missing if statement        
          setPageComplete(true);
        }
    });

    btnConfirm.setBounds(330, 225, 75, 20);
    btnConfirm.setText("Confirm");
```

What I'm trying to do is to build a menu where someone has to accept the terms and conditions before they can progress beyond a point. The default is to be unchecked but, when the box is checked, the next button will appear; if it is not, then the next button will remain inactive.

Comment: Your question is not complete. What are you trying to do and what exactly is not working?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just make the `Button` `final` and access it from within the `Listener`:

```
final Button btnConfirm = new Button(shell, SWT.CHECK);

btnConfirm.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e)
    {
        if (btnConfirm.getSelection())
            setPageComplete(true);
        else
            setPageComplete(false);
    }
});
```

---

Alternatively, get the `Button` from the `SelectionEvent`:

```
Button btnConfirm = new Button(shell, SWT.CHECK);

btnConfirm.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e)
    {
        Button button = (Button) e.widget;
        if (button.getSelection())
            setPageComplete(true);
        else
            setPageComplete(false);
    }
});
```

Comment: ...or just `setPageComplete(button.getSelection());`.